# Unable to execute mojo: Execution null of goal

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo, openmrs

When I try to set up OpenMRS Server, the console shows this error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openmrs.maven.plugins:openmrs-sdk-maven-plugin:5.9.0:setup (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: 
Failed to setup server: Unable to execute mojo: Execution null of goal org.openmrs.maven.plugins:openmrs-sdk-docker-maven-plugin:5.9.0:create-mysql failed: Unsupported protocol scheme found: 'http://127.0.0.1:2375/ -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: The configuration given `Unsupported protocol scheme found:` is wrong...

Comment: What exactly are you executing to get this error? As far as I know, OpenMRS consists of multiple projects. Which one are you trying to run? Is Docker installed on your system?